# How can we use Haskell with OSRM libraries?

Tags: haskell, ffi, osrm

We want to use libOSRM for routing. Currently we are calling its http services. For better performance, I want to call its dynamic library. When reading Haskell FFI, I guess I can compile and links its source (instead of compiled dynamic library) with my Haskell code.
1. Which method is better?
2. How can I do each alternative?

Note that OSRM is full of structs that I am not sure how to import into haskell. c2hsc does not install (cabal raises error!). I do not know how to link the whole source of OSRM, from the other hand.

Comment: Well, you need to write bindings.

Comment: As said above, you need to write bindings. As to how to do this, what would be best and so on: Those would be fairly lengthy answers covering a wide range of topics, and would probably still end up being specific to your usecase. Check out the Haskell FFI documentation, SO isn't really the right place for this kind of question.

Answer (score 2):

I prototyped some Haskell bindings going through an API and ABI compatible C wrapper: [libosrmc](https://github.com/daniel-j-h/libosrmc).

Feel free to give it a try and send in pull requests. It's exposing just a small part of the API and is based on OSRM version 5.4; you might need to invest some time. But the overall architecture and ideas still apply. [Here](https://github.com/daniel-j-h/libosrmc/blob/master/bindings/osrm_haskell.hs) are the Haskell bindings.

I recommend thinking twice about going the libosrm/FFI way with Haskell instead of sending HTTP requests: benchmark up-front if it's worth the troubles.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the project. I have some question: DO we have to wrap OSRM in C and then use it in Haskell? Is it possible to use the dynamic library (so, dylib, dll) and create appropriate structs using hpp files?
Another point: I guess it's worth of the trouble since OSRM is blazing fast and http-tcp overhead is a noticeable load !

Comment: You need the C wrapper for the FFI bindings and to have a stable ABI and API. Wrapping the C++ libosrm directly is not what I can recommend.

Answer (score 0):

you can look at https://github.com/daniel-j-h/hosrm-qa The project is PoC-only and uses HTTP OSRM API instead of Haskell FFI.

Comment: I strictly told that I wanna use libosrm and FFI!